# How to programatically add ServiceDebug behavior with endpoint?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I am working on a windows service to host WCF services for various projects.  Using the following `app.config` fragment:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="MyWcfService" behaviorConfiguration="MetaDataBehavior">
            <endpoint contract="MyWcfService" binding="wsHttpBinding" address="" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MetaDataBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I can expose the stock service "help" page and a `WSHttpBinding` on the same URL from within my service like so:

```
ServiceHost myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWcfService), new Uri(serviceAddress));
myServiceHost.Open()
```

I can then open a web browser and go to, e.g. `http://host:8001/services/MyWcfService`, and I see the standard WCF help page so I know the service is working.  (For the moment, let's ignore the security implications of exposing the help page.)  I can also access the `WSHttpBinding` endpoint ***on the same URL***.

We have now grown to host a lot of WCF services within this service, so I'm working to simplify the configuration by adding endpoints programatically to the `ServiceHost` object.  This all works just fine using `myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint()`.

The last piece I haven't been able to get programatically is enabling the `ServiceDebug` behavior on the same URL as the `WSHttpBinding`.  I have the following:

```
ServiceDebugBehavior sdb = myServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
if (sdb == null)
{
    sdb = new ServiceDebugBehavior()
    {
        HttpHelpPageEnabled = true,
        IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true
    };
    myServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(sdb);
}
else
{
    sdb.HttpHelpPageEnabled = true;
    sdb.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
    //sdb.HttpHelpPageUrl = new Uri(serviceAddress +"/help");
}
ServiceEndpoint endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(contract, new WSHttpBinding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(serviceAddress)));
myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(endpoint);
```

which works, so long as I a) change the address of the help page (as commented above), or b) change the URI on which the `WSHttpBinding` listens.  Conceptually this makes sense: .NET doesn't want to have two endpoints listening on the same URI.

My problem is that I have to maintain compatibility with existing applications using this service, which means my endpoint addresses cannot change.  If I can accomplish this through the `app.config`, why can I not accomplish this programatically?

Comment: If you are doing this all programatically, why are you hitting the else (sdb != null)? The ServiceDebugBehavior should not yet be created?

Comment: @felickz I have found ServiceDebugBehavior has been created automatically by the ServiceHost.

Comment: hmm, remove it and add yours always?

Comment: Tried that also.  Same issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can't actually ADD a ServiceDebugBehavior to a ServiceHost, what you have to do is modify the existing ServiceDebugBehavior (was having the same issue)

Example

```
 svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), adrbase);
            // Configure Your Service
            // Now for the ServiceDebugBehavior you want to modify (Example disable HTTP Help Page)
            svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;
```